# I need to read a line's end properly. Blank area problem

Tags: c, scanf

I have an input text to read with `fscanf` function. I can read some of lines. But, I could not read a line. Can you help?

My input.txt:

```
54,Zeynep Kucuk,62-46-59 
62,Osman Buyuk 
46,Gulay Er,25-23-32-1
```

I can read first and third line. But I have some problem with second line because its third position is empty.

But I can read surely if the input is like below

```
54,Zeynep Kucuk,62-46-59 
62,Osman Buyuk,0
46,Gulay Er,25-23-32-1
```

0 means Osman Buyuk has no friends.

Some part of my code below

```
int id;
char name[100];
char friends[100];
FILE *dosya = fopen("input.txt", "r");
struct node *root = NULL;
while (fscanf(dosya, "%d,%[^,],%s,%[^,],%s\n", &id, name, friends) == 3) {
    root = insertNewUser(root, id, name, friends);
}
```

After adding to tree my datas and print, expected output is:

```
31,NAME1 SURNAME1,16-23-45-3
21,NAME2 SURNAME2
10,NAME3 SURNAME3,12-31-1-5
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip the second and fourth items in the line, you must pass the assignment suppression character `*` before the `[`:

```
fscanf(dosya, "%d,%*[^,],%s,%*[^,],%s\n", &id, name, friends)
```

Note also that `%s` will stop on spaces: you might want to use `%[^,]` instead for `name` and `%[^\n]` for `friend` and you should not read the trailing newline with `\n`, which will read any pending whitespace, but instead `%*1[\n]` or `%c` to read the trailing byte. Passing the maximum number of characters to store into the destination arrays is also highly recommended to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.

Finally, if you need to handle lines with missing parts, it is better to read the file one line at a time with `fgets()` and parse the array with `sscanf()`.

Here is a modified version of your code fragment:

```
int id;
char buf[1024];
char name[100];
char friends[100];
FILE *dosya = fopen("input.txt", "r");
struct node *root = NULL;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, dosya)) {
    *friends = '\0';
    int n = fscanf(dosya, "%d,%*[^,],%99[^,],%*[^,],%99[^\n]", &id, name, friends);
    if (n >= 2)
        root = insertNewUser(root, id, name, friends);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response to my question. But, I still have a problem. Can u check my question again? Coz,I edited some parts. Maybe it is more clear now for understanding.